# Pdfx in Windows Flutter

Tags: windows, flutter, pdf

I am trying to show pdf files I have on a computer with [Pdfx](https://pub.dev/packages/pdfx) in the Windows version. It works sometimes but not all the time even for the same file.
My codes are like this:

```
PdfController(
        document:  PdfDocument.openFile(widget.pdfPath),
      );
```

and:

```
 Container(
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height*.75,
                  child: PdfView(
                      controller: pdfController,
                  ),
                ),
```

Any suggestions?

I tried to use it in futureBuilder or make the controler in initState but same result even worse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems I needed to dispose the pdfx controler.